# How to list tags from both posts and collections

Tags: jekyll

I have a tags.md which contain the code below, It list the tags from my _site/post.md

```
---
layout: default
title: Tags
---

{% for tag in site.tags %}
  <h2>{{ tag[0] }}</h2>
  <ul>
    {% for post in tag[1] %}
      <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

And I also have a Collections for work stuff, like work.md in the jekyll root directory and the post in there is inside `_work/`

How can I make the tags.md list the tags from both `_posts/*.md` and `_work/*.md`?

I realize I can't do something like this

```
{% for tag in site.tags %}
{% for tag in work.tags %}
  <h2>{{ tag[0] }}</h2>
  <ul>
    {% for post in tag[1] %}
      <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: No. This is not so easy. The `site.tags` variable only provides tags for posts, see [official Jekyll docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#tags-and-categories). How have you implemented tags for collections? Via [front matter defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/front-matter-defaults/)?

Comment: Yes, I implemented it with defaults front matter.
https://github.com/Physicys/physicys.github.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using site.documents should be your way to go, see https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/

> **site.documents**
> A list of all the documents in every collection.

Internally, posts are also treated as a collection here.

The first line below groups all documents by tag:

```
{% assign docs_by_tags = site.documents | group_by: 'tags' %}
{% for tag in docs_by_tags %}
<h2>{{ tag.name }}</h2>
<ul>
    {% for item in tag.items %}
    <li><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

BUT the result shows quoted tag names, which is not what we want.

#### A better solution to group arrays

Someone else already found a good way to group arrays in posts and collections back in 2015, see https://github.com/mushishi78/jekyll-group-by-array/blob/master/group-by-array.html - the project's readme has some sample code using the include file.

The code "extracts" tags or other attributes and pushes data to arrays before data is returned to be displayed.

#### The solution with both post and collection tag

Just use site.documents in the include as first parameter

```
{% comment %}based on https://github.com/mushishi78/jekyll-group-by-array{% endcomment %}

{% include group-by-array.html collection=site.documents field='tags' %}

<ul>
    {% for tag in group_names %}
    {% assign posts = group_items[forloop.index0] %}

    <li>
        <h2>{{ tag }}</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for post in posts %}
            <li>
                <a href='{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}'>{{ post.title }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

#### Reversing the posts order in the list

To reverse the post order under the tag, you can add a reversed to the for loop above:

`{% for post in posts reversed %}`

Comment: I tested your example code and it create a tag list from both collections, Still trying to figure out how to use that group-by-array.html, since `{% include group-by-array.html collection=site.posts field='tags' %}` only show the tag from _posts

Comment: You could try to run the code without the first parameter and use site.documents inside. Could not get the idea to run last night. Will look into it again.

Comment: Oh, I think by just changing the first parameter to site.documents will do the job, it list all the tags, though I'm not sure this is the correct way to do it. 
https://github.com/Physicys/physicys.github.io/commit/e7ae11a92232cdbc0a9552770697df06512f9062#diff-9bbec6bfa2d4557ee3ce82ef50b5d539d0e57201cc7353ea964255bca574b437

Comment: Also I just noticed that the post from a collection is list by date in reverse order, the oldest date post is at the top, can be fixed with `{% for post in site.work reversed %}`. But is that a default thing in collection?

Comment: It should work as expected, checked your repo. See my update in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

1. create plugin

```rb
module AllTagsFilter
  include Liquid::StandardFilters

  def all_tags(documents)
    counts = {}

    documents.each do |post|
      post['tags'].each do |tag|
        if counts[tag]
          counts[tag] += 1
        else
          counts[tag] = 1
        end
      end
    end

    tags = counts.keys
    tags.reject { |t| t.empty? }
      .map { |tag| { 'name' => tag, 'count' => counts[tag] } }
      .sort { |tag1, tag2| tag2['count'] <=> tag1['count'] }
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(AllTagsFilter)
```

2. create hooks

```rb
Jekyll::Hooks.register :documents, :post_write do |post|
  all_existing_tags = Dir.entries("_tags")
    .map { |t| t.match(/(.*).md/) }
    .compact.map { |m| m[1] }

  tags = post['tags'].reject { |t| t.empty? }
  tags.each do |tag|
    generate_tag_file(tag) if !all_existing_tags.include?(tag)
  end
end

def generate_tag_file(tag)
  File.open("_tags/#{tag}.md", "wb") do |file|
     file << "---\nlayout: jihetag\ntag-name: #{tag}\n---\n"
  end
end
```

3. create `_layout/tags.html`

```html
---
layout: default
---
<div class="container" id="tag_layout">
    <h2 class="text-bg-dark text-center p-4 rounded">带有"{{ page.tag-name }}"标签的文章</h2>
    <ul class="list-group">
        {% for post in site.posts %}
        {% if post.tags contains page.tag-name %}
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-{% if forloop.index == 1 %}primary{% endif %}{% if forloop.index == 2 %}secondary{%endif%}{% if forloop.index == 3 %}light{%endif%}{% if forloop.index == 4 %}info{%endif%}{% if forloop.index == 5 %}warning{%endif%}{% if forloop.index == 6 %}danger{%endif%}{% if forloop.index == 7 %}success{%endif%}{% if forloop.index == 8 %}dark{%endif%}">
            <a class="lh-lg text-warning lead text-decoration-none hvr-underline-from-left" href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
            <time>{{ post.date | date: "%Y-%m-%d" }}</time>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

**and** create Tag collection (is a folder starting with an underscore),`_tags`

**and** enable `_config.yml`

```yaml
collections:
  tags:
    output: true
    permalink: 'tags/:path/'
```

4. use it

```html
        {% assign group_post = site.tags | group_by:"tag" %}
        {% for page in group_post %}
        {% for item in page.items %}
        <h6 class="shadow rounded p-3" id="tag_group"><a href="{{ item.url }}" class="text-decoration-none text-reset">{{ item.title }}</a></h6>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

**Conclusion:** Through these four steps, it can display the `tag` attribute of articles under `_posts` and `collections` at the same time. First of all, thank you for the hints given above, which made me pay attention to the role of `site.documents`, otherwise it will not be used Such a "perfect" solution (if you have it, please remember to share it)
enjoy it! Ha ha

*Remind you*

> The preface of any document (including post and collection documents), if you use tag, it is all the default code, if you use `tags`, you need to change the corresponding tag, change the liquid filter to tags, such as `{% assign group_post = site.tags | group_by:"tags" %}`, note that here is `tags`, not `tag`